# I want to console.log() my data present in my MongoDB database, but i get an undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am using mongodb version 6 and i can not see the data i stored in my monogodb, and when i render to my broswer, i get an object that only has an id object, but my datas are not included.. this is my source code below, please help me

i am using mongodb version 6 and i can not see the data i stored in my monogodb, and when i render to my broswer, i get an object that only has an id object, but my datas are not included.. this is my source code below, please help me

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

 mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todoListDB');

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', {itemSchema});


const item1 = new Item({
  name: 'Welcome to your todolist'

 });

const item2 = new Item({
  name: 'HIT THE + BUTTON TO ADD A NEW ITEM.'
 });
const item3 = new Item({
  name: '<--Hit this to delete an item.'
 });



 const defaultItem = [item1,item2,item3];



 Item.insertMany(defaultItem);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  Item.find()

.then((foundItems) => {

  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems})

console.log(foundItems);

})
.catch((error) => {

 console.error(error); 

});
  
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

  const item = req.body.newItem;

  if (req.body.list === "Work") {
    workItems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/work");
  } else {
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});

app.get("/work", function(req,res){
  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work List", newListItems: workItems});
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructing schema creating issue while saving data. remove the curly braces in this line:

```
const Item = mongoose.model('Item', **itemSchema**);
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD88u.png)